# android spoledge aacdecoder outofmemory

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory

I need to know what that error means, what memory is it about :

```
E/dalvikvm-heap(31086): Out of memory on a 123496-byte allocation.

FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1269 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at com.spoledge.aacdecoder.AACPlayer.createDecodeBuffers(AACPlayer.java:518)
    at com.spoledge.aacdecoder.AACPlayer.playImpl(AACPlayer.java:438)
    at com.spoledge.aacdecoder.AACPlayer.play(AACPlayer.java:386)
    at com.spoledge.aacdecoder.AACPlayer.play(AACPlayer.java:338)
    at com.spoledge.aacdecoder.AACPlayer$1.run(AACPlayer.java:296)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

(I also use universalimageloader)

Answer (score 1):

It's about the heap memory, i.e. what you usually think of when someone says "this has XXX MB of memory". Looks like you're trying to take a bite that's too big for your handset. Perhaps you want streaming instead?

Comment: This is live-streaming (radio). Are you familliar with this library aacdecoder ?

Comment: Nope, but now that I look more clearly, you seem to be running out of memory trying to allocate 123KB. You need to find out what's using up all of your memory.